# How to use a ListView with an Iterator

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart, iterator

I would like to build a `ListView` of "Message Cards" for a timeline.  The message data comes from a Container class that has several filtering functions.  I only show one in the example.

EDIT: CLARIFICATOIN
I currently have this ListView working using a ListView.builder(), which depends on being able to access elements from the source data by index.

I would like to change it so that the elements come from an iterable which is generated on demand as the user scrolls the listview.

In the current working solution the Provider has a findByChildId which returns a List.  This list is generally very long and the user likely only wants to look at the last 100 or so messages.

So to not scan through many thousands of messages to return a few thousand of which only some are of interest I imagine using a findByChildId which yields items as the user scrolls.

````dart
class MessageData with ChangeNotifier {
  List<MessageRec> _messages;

  // New Iterable to lazily search only for items the user wants to look at
  Iterable<MessageRec> filterByChildId({String childId}) sync* {
    if (childId == null) {
      throw 'insanity check - Cannot search for null Child ID';
    }
    String previous;
    if (_messages != null) {
      for (MessageRec r in _messages) {
        if (r.properties['thread'] == childId) {
          if (previous == null || ymdFromDt(r.timeSent) != previous) {
            yield DateMark.fromDateString(previous); // Special Message inserted 
            previous = ymdFromDt(r.timeSent);
          }
          yield r;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // And many other supporting methods here.
}

Note: I assume the above works - this is my first forray into Iterables in Dart / flutter.

The above used to be a method that returned a list of MessageRec by iterating over the entire list and returning all matching items.

The ListView.builder could get items from the resulting list because the elements of a List can be accessed by index.

```dart
   ... Timeline Widget ...
 
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Consumer<MessageData>(
         builder: (context, messageData, _) {
            return ListView.builder((context, itemIndex) {
    
               // How to access elements from messageData.filterByChildId(childId) here
               MessageRec nextMessage = messageData.filterByChildId(childId)[itemIndex];
               // The above does not work because there is no indexing on Iterables
               
               return MessageCard.fromMessageRec(nextmessage);
               }
            );
         }
      );
    }
... snip rest of Widget methods
````

Or perhaps the answer lies in using a vanilla ListView with the `children` coming form the iterator, but I assume that would then still just end up creating all the messages in the list.

Comment: read carefully [Iterable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable-class.html) official documentation

Comment: Please give the answer if you can.  I have read the documentation.  Thank you.

Comment: and you did not see `Iterable.toList` / `Iterable.elementAt` methods?

Comment: That would just move the problem around.  I would then still end up using a List.  I may not have been clear in my question - I am trying to avoid using a List.  I will update the question to indicate this.

Comment: I'm trying to work out what exactly elementAt does. From the source code it seems to restart the iteration on every call.  That's even worse than just using a toList()!

Comment: and whats wrong with a `List`? does `Iterable` holds millions of items?

Comment: Yes it holds a very large number of items.

Comment: so instead of `Iterable<MessageRec>` return some `Map<int, MessageRec>` - that way you wuold be able to get `MessageRec` way faster than using long `Iterable`

Comment: I don't see how that is better than the original solution of returning a list.  Creating a Map is relatively expensive - every insert parses the hash to ensure the new index does not yet exist.  I must try to be more efficient.

Comment: you are not returning a list: you are returning `Iterable` - accessing one particular element in a map is like speed of light compared to iterable if you have millions of elements as you said

Comment: Yes but you have to weigh up the cost of maintaining the map.  Inserting and removing elements into a map comes at a cost.  So it depends on how often you scan over the Iterable compared to how often the list changes.  In my case I have a variety of situations, so will be better for copy to a List and others wont and some will just forever suck in terms of performance.  I am thinking of moving all of this into an SqlLite DB.  I think SQLite will be best for managing access to data that involves a mixed workload and I then only need to properly insert data into the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the name, `ListView` does not mandate the use of a `List`. You need to use a `List` only with the default constructor, but if you use `ListView.builder` you can use an `Iterable` to generate the values. Here is an example:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
  ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext _, int i) => 
      MessageCard.fromMessageRec(messageData.filterByChildId(childId).elementAt(i)
  );
```

As for the number of items allowed, the documentation of `ListView.builder` states that:

> This constructor is appropriate for list views with a large (or
> infinite) number of children because the builder is called only for
> those children that are actually visible.
> Blockquote

Comment: The documentation on [`Iterable.elementAt()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-core/Iterable/elementAt.html) has this to say *"May iterate through the elements in iteration order, ignoring the first index elements and then returning the next. Some iterables may have a more efficient way to find the element."* Which to me is a way to say that it's an inefficient O(N) operation, thus making your code O(N^2).